# Android: Do I really need Firebase custom authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app with `chat` function. I will go with `Firebase` for the backend and I don't know if I need `custom authentication` in my app.

All I need from the user when he login is a `Username` and `Phonenumber`. I verify the phone number sending sms with a code, so basically I could add the username and the phonenumber directly to the json-tree(database) when phonenumber is verified.

**Is there any reason that I would need to authenticate the user using JWT?** I also store the username and phone number in SharedPrefrence after I verify the number.

Comment: Does this mean anyone knowing a user's phone number can log into your Firebase instace?
Isn't passwords supposed to be secret, and easily changeable?

Comment: @sfThomas Every user has a phone number, saved locally in sharedPreference. If the number is verified and it is from that phone he can acces the database. If it is not he will not be redirected to activities that can acces the database. But you say that I should only allow authenticated users to acces the database. In that case I think I need to  change the security rules so only authenticated users can acces it. Right now I have just read/write true. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:** Yes. I need custom authentication for my app because everybody can do reverse engineering and see the API url and acces it with these default rules:

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
}
```

If I authenticate my users with tokens(JWT) generated from the secret key, uid and another data on a trusted server(don't store secret key on your app code), the server will not be accesible for everyone. Of course I need to change the security rules too, so only authenticated users can acces it:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      "users": {
        "$user_id": {
          // grants write/read access to the owner of this user account
          // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
          ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
          ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You definitely need to authenticate users in order to secure the database. But whether you need **custom** authentication is a different matter. For example: you could store users as `username@cristisdomain.com` (so hard-coding the domain name) and then user their phone number as their password. That way you're using email+password for the auth. That said: it is probably easiest to mint your own tokens. There are enough libraries available and it gives you full control over what goes into the `auth` variable for your security rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Your idea with email+password is really nice, but I already managed to generate tokens with the java library from documentation, so I will stick to it. I updated the security rules so only auth users can acces it. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Yup, sounds good. I'm just in a literal mood this morning and the answer to "do I really need custom authentication?" is strictly speaking a "nope, not needed". You definitely have a case where you *should* and can easily use custom authentication, but there are other options. :-)